# Pass ADFS Token in WebClient Call

Tags: asp.net, webclient, wif, adfs2.0

I am using ADFS 2.0 and WIF to authenticate and authorize my users to an ASP.Net MVC 4 application, WebAppA. WebAppA uses WebClient.DownloadString(url) to call another WebAppB and I would like to pass the delegated user's credentials to WebAppB to retrieve customized content for the user.

I see several examples of a web application calling a WCF service using CreateChannelActingAs, but this is not quite my situation.

Is there a way for WebAppA to retrieve the ActAs (or OnBehalfOf?) token for WebAppB and pass it with WebClient to WebAppB? I have seen a few possibilities, including the "bearer" Authorization header and inserting a cookie into the headers, but I don't quite understand these examples and it seems like something's missing, like how to use the BootstrapContext from WebAppA to retrieve and serialize the token for WebAppB.

Thanks for any help!

--Mark

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could have WebAppA call the STS and request an *ActAs* token for WebAppB, using the original token (the one intended for WebAppA) as the input, but this is normally used for web services (and it might be overkill). Looks like you are just GET'ing a page from WebAppB. Why not just use basic auth, SSL and pass a parameter of the user making the request? (in essence using a *trusted subsystem* approach).

Comment: I am able to retrieve the _ActAs_ token for use with WebAppB. However, I'm not clear on how to use it in my call to WebAppB. I am, indeed, looking for a way to do this in the GET from WebAppB.

I would like to do this because I'm already using WIF on WebAppB because sometimes the user makes direct requests of it, and sometimes they make a request of WebAppB which retrieves information from WebAppB on the users' behalf.